# How to set a starting point mysql query depending on the value

Tags: php

I have a table storing date and other information. I am saving date in MM-DD format.

To display the data I want to pull the data depending on the current data and it's working fine for me.

Now I want to show the data of current date and next 2 days. I managed to create a query using date array but when month change my date change to the next number such 06-31 and 06-32

Here is my codes:

```
<?php
$date = date('Y/m/d');
$explode = explode("/", $date);
$date = array($explode[1] . "-" . $explode[2], $explode[1] . "-" . ($explode[2]+1), $explode[1] . "-" . ($explode[2]+2));
$i = 0;
while($i < 3){
    $query= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM ramadan WHERE UID = '$ID' AND Ramadan_Date ='$date[$i]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
?>

<tr class="normal">
<th rowspan="row"><? echo $date[$i]."-".$explode[0]; ?></th>
<th rowspan="row" colspan="1" ><? echo $row['Sehri']; ?></th>
<th rowspan="row" colspan="1" ><? echo $row['Iftari']; ?></th>
</tr>
<?php
    $i++; 
}
?>
```

Comment: On a sidenote, your code block itself is pointing out the syntax highlighting issue

Comment: Sidenote 2: always store date as UNIX timestamp or MYSQL date

Comment: Syntax error might be in copying from there to here but it's working. Thanks for that.
Side Note2: I am using Date as a reference because it will be used same values every year. such as Islamic Prayer times. Any solution please?

Comment: Use [`date_add`](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)